# How to convert a ReactJS web application into a mobile friendly application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

I am currently working on a complex web application written mainly in ReactJS with Redux which uses Node and Docker containers for deployment.

As the app is currently mainly used by laptop users, our next goal is to make the application mobile friendly (mainly iOS) and allow the user to utilize the phone's camera to upload photos straight to the app.

It's my first time trying to make a web application mobile-friendly so I am wondering what's the best approach for doing so. I've considered using CSS media queries to adjust the layout based on the screen size but we've come across a few drawbacks such as pop-ups or modals not looking as expected.

Should we go down the route of rewriting the code in React Native (not ideal approach), or are there any other better suited solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options, most of which would have been better if implemented at the beginning of the project. Mobile-first UI development is by far the easiest way to deal with different device sizes, as you have already guessed with elements such as reducing your modals.

I would absolutely recommend using a UI library that comes with a responsive grid solution if you're not already using one. Available ones include, but are not limited to, [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/), [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) (using a react implementation such as [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)) and [Ant Design](https://ant.design/).

As to whether you should do a rewrite, that is up to you to compare the costs and benefits. What I would suggest is, instead of planning to go for something specific such as iOS, plan to support device sizes instead. Any decent UI framework will work in terms of common breakpoints that abstract you from thinking in terms of "iPhone X in landscape" to something like "Extra small", "Small", "Medium", "Large" and so forth.

Comment: Hi Dean, unfortunately our web app started life as PC-only approach and there are so many components in use already that starting with mobile-first development is unfortunately impossible.

As far as layout goes, we use a lot of Ant D components together with flex box layout. So do you suggest going down the route of media responsive styling and layout? What happens if I want to integrate the use of mobile's camera for example, would I be better of adding React Native modules?